# NullPointerException Initialize View in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i use Fragment to hold my content in TabLayout.
Inside it, i have Button. When i try to instantiate in Fragment class i get this following error :

```
com.example.fanjavaid.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.example.fanjavaid.tablayout.fragment.AccountFragment.onCreateView(AccountFragment.java:27)
          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
```

Here is my code in **onCreateView(...)**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RelativeLayout mFragmentAccount = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_account);

        mBtnAddPerson = (Button) mFragmentAccount.findViewById(R.id.add_person);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mFragmentAccount.getContext().getAssets(), "/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
        mBtnAddPerson.setTypeface(font);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, mFragmentAccount,true);
    }
```

And here is my Fragment XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_account"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello Android!"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add People"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What did I miss?

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to add the stacktrace. Please add it to your question.

Comment: yeah, please add the log.

Comment: question updated, thank you

Comment: victor and Slamper have answered your Qn. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to findViews before inflating them.
First inflate the View and then access it's children.

please try this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mFragmentAccount = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container,true);

    mBtnAddPerson = (Button) mFragmentAccount.findViewById(R.id.add_person);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mFragmentAccount.getContext().getAssets(), "/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
    mBtnAddPerson.setTypeface(font);

    return mFragmentAccount;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me in which line of my suggested code the NP occurs ?

Comment: in this line : `mBtnAddPerson = (Button) mFragmentAccount.findViewById(R.id.add_person);` when instantiate button

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get your View from your Activity. You have to inflate your fragment.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_account, container, false);
```

Comment: It's also better to place the code that is accessing view in `onViewCreated(..)`

Answer (score 0):

the NP error, as Slapmer and Victor pointed out, is because you are trying to access `View` before you created(inflated) `View`.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, mFragmentAccount,true);
    }
```

It's better to add code that access `View` in `onViewCreated(...)`, like this :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout mFragmentAccount = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_account);
    mBtnAddPerson = (Button) mFragmentAccount.findViewById(R.id.add_person);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mFragmentAccount.getContext().getAssets(), "/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
    mBtnAddPerson.setTypeface(font);
```

}

Happy Coding!