# Watcher 5 character min

Tags: android, count, character, min, textwatcher

I got some issues with my code. In my fragment i got error like  addTextChangedListener android.text.TextWatcher on a null object reference.
Im new in Android Environment

I want to create in my EditText field min characters at 5 and app crash every time.

Edit 1:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_game_details, container, false);

    typeMessageToPost = view.findViewById(R.id.Details);

    typeMessageToPost.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

return view;}


private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher=new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        number_of_character.setText(String.valueOf(140-s.length()));
    }
};}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException Initialize View in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962341/nullpointerexception-initialize-view-in-fragment)

Comment: Without that line number_of_character.setText(String.valueOf(140-s.length())); start worked but now i got question how demand at least 5 characters ?

Comment: Try this in your code .`@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() < 5) {
                Log.e("MIN", s.length() + "");
                return;
            }
            number_of_character.setText(String.valueOf(140-s.length()));
        }`

Comment: Thx its working, but still dosent do what i want :<

Comment: While you are editing text box and you write for example "Game" in right corner of my EditText should show red error text " At least 5 character" and make you unable to move anywhere else, thats what i want

Comment: There is any option to help me becous i never use this Watchers before and dont know what to do ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't assign anything to typeMessageToPost. And in a fragment, you use onCreateView() instead of onCreate() to initialize your views. So change your onCreate() method to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    typeMessageToPost = view.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
    typeMessageToPost.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

    return view;
}
```

**EDIT**

To check if you have at least 5 characters is no big deal:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.length() < 5) {
        number_of_character.setText("Error text you want to display");
    } else {
        // Whatever you want to do once the input text has at least 5 characters
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx its working but now how to return error when there is no at least 5 characters ?